# CMake - Changing shared library link options

Tags: c++, c, cmake

I want to manipulate the linker call in my linker trampoline python script, but for the life of me I cannot get CMake to respect the `CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY` value. It always uses the `CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER` for linking. If I switch to an `add_executable` and instead use `CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` this works perfectly. Is there anyway to convince CMake to respect the setting of `CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY`?

## A trivial CMakeLists.txt

```
cmake_minimum_required( VERSION 3.12 )

project( mylib )

include( CMakePrintSystemInformation )

add_library( mylib SHARED mylib.cpp )
```

## A toolchain excerpt

I've tried this in both a toolchain file and an `-C` pre-cache option.

```
set( CMAKE_LINKER "/path/to/linker_trampoline.py" )
set( CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY "<CMAKE_LINKER> --CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER <CMAKE_CXX_COMPILER> --CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CXX_FLAGS <CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CXX_FLAGS> --LANGUAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS <LANGUAGE_COMPILE_FLAGS> --LINK_FLAGS <LINK_FLAGS> --CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CREATE_CXX_FLAGS <CMAKE_SHARED_LIBRARY_CREATE_CXX_FLAGS> --SONAME_FLAG <SONAME_FLAG> --TARGET_SONAME <TARGET_SONAME> --TARGET <TARGET> --OBJECTS <OBJECTS> --LINK_LIBRARIES <LINK_LIBRARIES>" CACHE STRING "" FORCE )
```

Answer (score 1):

**Works as expected with CMake version 3.10**

I have tried your example. No issues with your intention. The only differences are, I tried this with an older version of **CMake** and placed the variable declarations directly in the file *CMakeLists.txt* (Should be placed in a toolchain file).

***CMakeLists.txt*:**

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.10)

project(mylib)

include(CMakePrintSystemInformation)

set (CMAKE_LINKER "/path/to/link.sh")
set (CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY "<CMAKE_LINKER> <OBJECTS>")

add_library(mylib SHARED mylib.cpp)
```

I have shortened the declaration of `CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY` here because I only pass the object files to the following script.

***link.sh*: (Simple print the object files)**:

```
#!/bin/bash

echo "$@"
```

**Output:**

```
$ cmake CMakeLists.txt
$ make
[ 50%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/mylib.cpp.o
[100%] Linking CXX shared library libmylib.so
CMakeFiles/mylib.dir/mylib.cpp.o
[100%] Built target mylib
$
```

*link.sh* will be definitely executed. You an ignore the formal message about linking *libmylib.so*. The library will be never created (with my linker command).

**CMake version:**

```
$ cmake --version
cmake version 3.10.2

CMake suite maintained and supported by Kitware (kitware.com/cmake).
$
```

I have seen you have already created an issue or rather a feature request on the [CMake project site](https://gitlab.kitware.com/cmake/cmake/-/issues/20876).

Comment: Thank you for looking into this as well. This is what I found would work too. Brad King says, that we're not supposed to use the toolchain for this - surprising - so I've written a module as suggested.

Answer (score 0):

### Response from Kitware

Brad King commented:

`CMAKE_CXX_LINK_EXECUTABLE` and `CMAKE_CXX_CREATE_SHARED_LIBRARY` are not meant to be set by toolchain files directly (and if either seems to work it is only by accident). They are not meant to be cached either. They are set in CMake's platform/compiler information modules which are loaded after the toolchain file. For toolchain files meant to cross-compile to a custom platform, they can set `CMAKE_SYSTEM_NAME` to the name of the target platform, set `CMAKE_MODULE_PATH` to a custom directory, and then add `Platform/<os>*.cmake` modules with such settings for that platform.

To hook in to the link line for an existing platform another approach will be needed. #18316 is related.